# Do we need the Angular Library tslib peer dependency when publishing a library?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-library

I've created a library that does not directly import anyting from `tslib`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/validatorts

Do we need to keep this peer dependency.  If not how do we remove it when we generate the library build?

[Also asked on the repository](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1565)

Answer (score 1):

The creators of `ng-packagr` got back to me.  The FESM package generated by the Angular Package Format uses it so I'll just leave it as a peer dependency.

This is a link to their answer:

https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1565#issuecomment-597563767